# Android Accessing get external directory

Tags: android, storage, sd-card, android-external-storage

Now, I am working on data transmission using bluetooth. I have such problem in selecting file in SD card/ internal storage.

1. I am already put permission in manifest :
2. I am using this command to get access the file 
   File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
3. But when I am check using this command  if (sdCard.canRead()) , it can't read the path.

Anyone have the solution within my problem? Thanks anyway

Comment: Can you add your manifest to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved.
The problem is related with new android SDK. We need to add additional permission.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

[The Android Dev resources has a good guide on this.](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteExternalStorage)

Assuming you have all the correct permissions, you could be facing issues where the storage is not mounted or there is not enough space. The guide explains how to check the state of the External Storage Dir, etc.

Comment: I will try and post the result ASAP. Thanks anyway

Comment: @albert92 Sounds good, If you can add the manifest and some of your code to your question it might be easier to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the following line to the AndroidManifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

From android SDK version 4, you need to add that line to access external storage by your app.

Some of other issues are, (Check whether phone detects the SD card)

- SD Card is Not Clean
- Battery Voltage
- Card Slot is Squeezed
- Metal Wires in the Card Slot Get Rusty and Twisted
- Malware Invade SD Card
- SD Card is not Formatted Properly
- SD Card is Broken
- The Phone Breakdown

Comment: Yes, I was put the permission. Here is my manifests:

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

I am using internal storage actually. Is it regarded with lollipop ? I am using this android version actually. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Did you put that outside of the Application tag?